# what am I doing to reduce the apk size in eclipse?

Tags: android

I have a lot of picture in my project and I don't delete My Picture because i need them, so my application size is very large (over than 100Mb)
could you help me what am I doing to reduce the apk size in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your apk size is 100 mb it is very big.

One thing please enable proguard in your application. You are using eclipse

then please uncomment

`proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt` line

from 
`project.properties` file.

Second you can use [apk expansion](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) technique for that.

Here is one more tutorial for that

http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.in/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html

Comment: Thank's alot... this method is my favorite one.

Answer (score 1):

1: You can compress your images in resources with best Online Compression Tools i.e [Tinypng](https://tinypng.com/).

2: You can also generate [9 Patch](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) Images.

3: Try using `abiFilters` for reducing your apk size.

Comment: could you tell me more about abiFilters?

Comment: 1. `armeabiv-v7a`: Version 7 or higher of the ARM processor. Most Android phones released from 2011-15 are using this.  2. `arm64-v8a`: 64-bit ARM processors. Found on new devices, like the Samsung Galaxy S6.  3. `armeabi`: Older phones using v5 or v6 of the ARM processor.  4. x86: Mostly used by tablets, and by emulators.  5. `x86_64`: Used by 64-bit tablets.  In order to make your apk compatible with some of the phones.  Ex. `build.gradle` add `ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }` in `defaultConfig` section.

Answer (score 0):

you can compress the `.jpg` files as much as possible, this should greatly reduce the size of your `.apk` file. A tool such as [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) which is free should help you do this. It has great resizing options.

Comment: I compress pictures with adobe photoshop but apk size's reduction is not what ever I want. thank's

Answer (score 0):

Convert all your images into .jpg which is in .png.
It will reduce some size.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your resources folder to check unused images and drawables

use image format JPG in comparison to PNG

Use progurad to obfuscate the code and it will reduce the apk size also

check RAW and assets folder to check unused stuff

Comment: thanks, beforehand I used this method but its not good working.